# Does "wollen" ever function like English "will" to signal a future event (no volition)

Tags: modal-verb

**Question**

Does "wollen" ever function like English "will" (or "be going to" if in the past tense) to signal a future event without any element of volition?

**Question Explained**

I came to have the question upon reading passages like these.

> A: Da erzählte er [der Königssohn] ihr, er wäre von einer bösen Hexe verwünscht worden, und niemand hätte ihn aus dem Brunnen erlösen können als sie allein, und morgen **wollten** sie zusammen in sein Reich gehen.  ([Der Froschkönig oder der eiserne Heinrich](http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/der_froschkonig_oder_der_eiserne_heinrich).)
>
> B: Wenn du [der Arzt] zu einem Kranken gerufen wirst, so will ich [der Gevatter Tod] dir jedesmal erscheinen: steh ich zu Häupten des Kranken, so kannst du keck sprechen, du **wolltest** ihn wieder gesund machen, und gibst du ihm dann von jenem Kraut ein, so wird er genesen; steh ich aber zu Füssen des Kranken, so ist er mein, und du musst sagen, alle Hilfe sei umsonst und kein Arzt in der Welt könne ihn retten.  ([Der Gevatter Tod](http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/der_gevatter_tod).)
>
> C: Der Tod stellte sich, als ob er seinen Wunsch erfüllen **wollte**, langte ein frisches, grosses Licht herbei, aber weil er sich rächen wollte, versah er’s beim Umstecken absichtlich, und das Stöckchen fiel um und verlosch. (Ibid.)

In the following I try to explain what the question is by making it concrete.

The question, as applied to the passages, would give us:

- For A, is the prince declaring his, her or their volition, intention, etc. that a certain event (i.e. their going to his kingdom) should occur tomorrow, or is he simply making a prediction* that it will?
- For B, is Death instructing the doctor to declare his intention to
  heal the sick or simply to make a prediction that a certain event
  (the doctor's healing the sick) will occur?
- For C, does Death pretend as if he intended to fulfill his godson's
  wish or simply as if he were going to?**

(*Please don't read too much into this word *prediction*.  I only mean what may be involved in answering, "Will she be here tomorrow?" with "Yes she will," to mean that that was the itinerary.  **If this distinction is not clear, consider pretending as if the door were going to open, e.g. by standing next to it and not any other door.)

If your answer is that *wollen* signals volition of some sort in these passages, could you then explain the strangeness as follows?

- In A, the prince comes out saying that he and the princess *want* or *intend* to go to his kingdom.  How does he know her mind so well?  Shouldn't he just speak for himself?  It'd be far more natural for him to address simply what they were going to do the next day.  (What I mean is that that would be the more natural characterization the narrator can give to the prince.)
- In B, Death comes out instructing the doctor to say that he *wants* or *intends* to cure the patient.  Now, isn't that what the doctor wants or intends every time?  Does any doctor ever need to say that?  Again it'd be more natural for the doctor to say (or Death to instruct him to say) simply what he was going to do this time.
- In C, it comes out Death pretends as if he wanted to do something.  But if you read the whole story, Death was angry with his godson and the most he would pretend would be *going* to let him off though he does not *want* to.

In all these passages, reading *wollen* as a mark of volition seems to do violence to the narrative.

**Addendum**

Please see [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24520/can-you-use-wollen-in-konjunktiv-ii-simply-to-mean-what-will-happen-no-voliti) and [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24522/how-do-you-go-from-wollen-in-konjunktiv-ii-in-indirect-speech-to-direct-speech) related question on *wollen*.

I asked a similar [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13545/does-german-sollen-ever-function-like-english-shall-to-indicate-a-future-or) on *sollen* and indeed got answers to the effect that *sollen* in certain contexts signals a possibility rather than expectation. Thanks.

Comment: @A: It's a fairy tale where the prince can assume that every girl wants to come with him to his kingdom.^^

Comment: Additionally, at second thought, it has something to do with reported speech. I can imagine person X calling person Y and saying "Ich komme gleich zu euch." Some time later person Z asks Y "Warum ist denn X noch nicht hier?" and Y answers "Keine Ahnung, er *wollte* eigentlich gleich kommen."

Comment: @Chris Just so I understand properly, you mean that Y in your example could not be understood to mean what X *wanted* to do at any time, but only what X *was going* to do and that therefore there must be a use of *wollen* having nothing to do with volition?

Comment: Well, for me "going to" contains volition. What I wanted to express: Even if there isn't "wollen" in direct speech, if it is transformed to indirect speech "wollen" can be there. - Y, who transforms X's direct speech to indirect speech, makes an assumption about X's volition; although X didn't use "wollen" in his direct speech.

Comment: @Chris If so, can X's initial statement have been about A (= X's wife)? I.e. X says to Y, "A kommt gleich"; and when Z asks Y, Y answers, "Keine Ahnung, sie wollte eigentlich gleich kommen." Can Y answer like this? If you say yes, then are you going to see a volition in this *wollte* as well? Namely, is Y attributing a volition to A based on X's statement about what A, his wife, will do? (If you say no to the earlier question, this last question does not arise.)

Comment: It's getting tricky!^^ Idiomatically I would expect "Keine Ahnung, sie *sollte* eigentlich gleich kommen." - Here, Y hasn't talked to A in person and doesn't know her intentions. Y only knows what X said about A's intentions. - I know, it gets complicated! I cannot explain this phenomenon in its entirety; so don't let yourself be confused by my comments, please. :-)

Comment: Yes, "der Vulkan *wollte*..." would be totally unidiomatic. (And the most common word would be "ausbrechen" for "eruptieren".)

Comment: @Chris I'm sorry I asked you a question on "Keine Ahnung, der Vulkan sollte eigentlich gleich eruptieren," but deleted it because the system said don't be chatting. But that left your answer dangling.

Comment: I'm a little confused... "wollte" is either a past form or a subjunctive. As such it CANNOT be "will" because that is present tense (and has no past form). So as it stands the whole first part of the question contains examples that in no way exemplify the problem. Think you could fix that?

Comment: As much as I do believe that all your edits are helpful in clarifying your question I somehow feel that the text body became a bit long to read, Any chance to make all this a bit shorter so that future visitors could see more quickly what your question was about?

Comment: I'm voting -1 now because I really think the "wollten" -examples are a problem. Why are they in there? They have NOTHING to do with the question.

Comment: @Emanuel The question is on *wollen* in all its inflections, including *wollten*. Do you think *wollte*, *wolltest* etc. work very differently and should be treated separately from *will*, *willst* etc.? Can you say more what the problem is?

Comment: Yes. You're asking whether "wollen" can express the same as future-will. The example you give contain past tense or subjunctive...meaning, there is NO future-will in them. Whatever the "wollte(n)" expresses. It's NOT English "will". So they have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Emanuel The question is about whether *wollen* can be 100% future (or perhaps more accurately 0% volition) and the English *will* is meant to be just an example of such a word. The question does not ask whether *wollen* and *will* behave alike in all their inflections. In other words, the question is not even about *will* and can be stated without it. But it's not critical as many members, including yourself, addressed the thing I wanted to know.

Comment: The point is that NO verb in its past tense can EVER talk about the future. To me, the way you phrased your question is the same as having this title "Can 'to drink' talk about the future?" and then give as an example "I drank a tea." The example makes no sense in that context. To address your question I only went by the title. I started to read the body but then stopped because it was confusing.

Comment: @Catomic... yes, that's what I want to restrict it to because you explicitly mention English "will" and this one is restricted in that way. Same as the German future auxiliary "werden". It speaks about a future relative to time of utterance, not time of story.

Comment: c) agreed. a+ b) Take a look at this: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/will-or-would   The definition for "will" say (among other things): talks about the future. The definition for "would" does not contain that sentence.

Comment: WEll, that's what I'm saying. Future refers to time of utterance. You're complicating things by throwing reported speech and it's forms in there. I know you've probably studied this well but let me tell you that to me as a native speaker of German, the "wollte(n)"  in A and C (especially A) do not feel the least bit like a subjunctive/Konjunktiv (whatever). They feel like past and I REALLY have to force my brain to read anything but simple past.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26153/discussion-between-catomic-and-emanuel).

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: No, not in contemporary German.

Slightly longer answer:

"wollen" implies an *intention*, not a prediction. It literally translates to "want" in English - and works the same in every way I can think of right now.

The translation for "will" (referring to the future) is "werden".

That being said, the sentences you quote are written in outdated German, and today no one would use those constructions any longer - but this might actually be where engl. "will" and germ. "wollen" have a common root (pure speculation though).

- In A, I would still interpret it as a contemporary "wollen", although I agree that there are undertones of "werden" in it.
- In B, one would replace "wollten" with "würden" in today's language.
- In C the situation seems quite clear to me that it means "wollen" in a contemporary sense.

Sorry, if this makes the answer slighly confusing...

Comment: There is one way it doesn't work like English *want*: **Die Frau will ein UFO gesehen haben** = ***The woman claims to have seen UFO***. But well this is probably a higher level of German language.

Comment: @Barth Zalewski By "higher level" do you mean that a "deep grammar" analysis of  *wollen* in your example would go e.g. the woman wanting it known, accepted etc. that she has seen UFO, where *wollen* is at a higher grammatical node than is suggested by surface grammar?

Comment: I mean that this way of usage of modal verbs is taught at higher levels of German. It means that is her opinion that she saw Ufo and nobody actually believes her but she claims so. Each modal verb in German can be use in an extended way. For example **Sie dürften schon weit weg sein** means ***They are probably very far away already***.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question: *wollen* can never serve as an exact replacement for *werden*; werden is the neutral form of something happening in the future. However, *wollen* almost always refers to an event in the future, when used in Indikativ Präsens; also, it can serve to express wishes or intentions:

1. Ich will einen Keks essen. (wish, and if I could do it, I'll eat it in the future)
2. Ich will eine Runde laufen gehen. (intention, and this will happen in the future)

Especially (2) is a strong indicator for a future event and I suppose it is the reason why *wollen* became the future auxiliary of choice in many germanic languages. But it will never be as neutral as "werden", as volition/intention will always be retained, which can be demonstrated easily:

3. Morgen werde ich in den Krieg ziehen.
4. Morgen will ich in den Krieg ziehen.

The first sentence is a neutral statement about a future event, wich does not allow to discern whether the speaker wants to take part in war or not; but in (4), it can safely assumed that he does not object. Someone who does not want to partake in a war, would stick to *werden* or use *müssen/sollen* instead.

This is why it is usually impossible to use it when there is no subject that is able to have wishes/intentions:

5. *Das Schiff will sinken.
6. *Laut Wettervorhersage will es morgen regnen.

It has never been different for German, as far as I know. But let's replace *wollen* with *werden* in (2):

7. Ich will noch eine Runde laufen gehen.
8. Ich werde noch eine Runde laufen gehen.

Concerning the question whether the event will take place or not, it will basically the same in many everyday situations. Therefore *wollen* can indeed serve to express a temporal category, with an additional connotation of intention.

**Another Edit:**
Middle High German did not yet have a **grammaticalized** future tense. The future events therefore had to be expressed by other means, which, AFAIK, where:

> Ich werde arbeitend ("I become working", inchoative aspect)
>   Ich muss arbeiten (I have to work ("must"))
>   Ich will arbeiten (I want to work ("will"))
>   Ich soll arbeiten (I am supposed to work ("shall"))

To develop into a grammaticalized, syntactical structure, it is necessary to erase the lexical meaning of words. This happened to english will, which does no longer carry the lexical meaning of "want". Most likely, the inchoative aspect was fully grammaticalized, in a way the similar Passiv is grammaticalized today (werden + Partizip Präsens = Inchoativ, werden + Partizip Perfekt = Vorgangspassiv). It was just that the -d of the Partizip Präsens was dropped. With a fully grammaticalized future tense in place, the process, that would most likely have led to the erasure of the lexical meanings of either *wollen*, *müssen*, *sollen*, stopped. Therefore, *wollen*/*sollen* and certainly not *müssen* can *never* be used exactly as *werden* is used, simply for the fact that they do not ever come without their lexical meaning.

*Sollen* is somewhat of an exception: it is often used when the Vorgangspassiv is put into the future, as otherwise one either had to drop future tense or use *werden* two times. Example:

> Die Straße soll wegen Bauarbeiten für sechs Wochen gesperrt werden.

It is quite clear that "sollen" has little modal meaning left here. But I'm not decided whether it is viable to assume a separate grammaticalized future tense with sollen or not.

Comment: I disagree with "never", see my answer for examples

Comment: That is why I wrote "can never serve as an *exact* replacement". *Wollen* always "taints" the temporal category with a modal one.

Comment: @Emanuel: enhanced my answer.

Comment: Still, take my last example and explain how this sentence is any different with "wollen". When it comes to translating it to English you CLEARLY get "will" and not "want to" so from a students perspective "wollen" does mean "will" there. I think the words are synonymous there and synonyms can have differences in nuances... otherwise we would have very few synonyms of anything.

Comment: I think what would be okay to say is that "wollen" can never be English "will" that has NO component of volition whatsoever... like "The sky will be dark." There's zero volition in that and "wollen" wouldn't work.

Comment: @Emanuel: About your last example: Yes, it would be translated into "will", which doesn't mean *werden* and *wollen* is exactly the same there in German. It just means that English doesn't have a modal system which is as sophisticated as the German one.

Comment: An interesting find regarding the olden days: https://books.google.de/books?id=LLVQAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA125&dq="will+ich+mich+stellen"&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMIoIHRvrLoxgIVQ7UUCh1f_wUU#v=onepage&q=%22will%20ich%20mich%20stellen%22&f=false ... point 45 says "... und ich will unter den Söhnen Isreals wohnen und will ihr Gott sein." Wäre interessant, ob da wirklich "wollen" gemeint ist.

Comment: Little comment regarding "das Schiff will sinken" and "es will regnen": Actually, those two *would* have been correct two hundred years ago (Adelung's dictionary from 1801 mentions the first as an example for his 8th definition of the word [http://www.zeno.org/Adelung-1793/A/Wollen]); there's also "es will Abend werden" in Lukas 24:29 - which is the title of Bach's cantata BWV 6.

Comment: Grimm is also interesting in this context: "die eigenbedeutung [i.e. "to want"] von wollen kann weiter zu einem auxiliar verblassen, das in verbindung mit einem inf. temporale oder modale funktion übernimmt, eine entwicklung, die nicht auf das deutsche beschränkt ist, sondern auch an. und besonders ags./engl. für die verbalflexion wichtig wird. *ein rest der eigenbedeutung bleibt dem verbum wollen aber in der deutschen sprache immer, auch wo es hilfsverb ist*." [emphasis mine] [http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW26466#XGW26466]

Comment: "Die Straße soll..." - if I wanted to express the future, I'd drop the Futur and use "Die Straße wird ... gesperrt". I'd understand your example sentence to mean "I've heard that they will...". Do you have more contemporary examples for this?

Answer (score 1):

As I have said in the comments, the examples you give do not illustrate the question. "will" is a present form. It has a subjunctive/conditional form (would) but no past form. And it wouldn't make sense. Either something will happen in the future (from now) or not. You cannot form a past tense of a future tense (I think that is impossible in any language but I don't know).

The other answers say that "wollen" can never be used as future-"will". I have to slightly disagree with that.

> Ich will das mal überhören.
>   Ich will das mal so stehen lassen.
>   Vereinfachend will ich das im Folgenden nur noch als „Bereich der Gesamtinotropie“ bezeichnen.

To me, this is more a statement about what you will do than it is about what you want.  The idea of "wollen" is in there, too, of course and the overlap is natural since  statements about intentions for the future are inherently both... a statement about the future and a statement about volition. That's how English "will" became what it is. It was volition at first, too. 
But as for my examples I'd say they're about 70% future focused. You can replace the "will" in the examples with "werde" and have essentially the same sentence.

Especially the last one, since it contains a future marker "im Folgenden". If it were strictly volition the statement would express that you are going to want to call it that from now on... never mind whether you actually will or not.

Comment: As you are referring to me: I said that "wollen" can never serve as an exact replacement, however, it *can* serve as a proper replacement to signal a future event. But different from *werden*, *wollen* is not neutral, as it puts emphasis on the speakers intentions.

Comment: @Veredomon... if I say "Ich werde das ab jetzt so machen." then I am stating my intentions. Whether they'll become a reality is not known yet because it's future. "werden" is often used to talk about intentions that way.

Comment: Yes, but you stay neutral about your feelings. *Werden* is about a future event, *wollen* is about modality that implies/will lead to a future event. That's a difference.

Comment: @Veredomon... in the last example, you don't actually know that. Maybe the author doesn't like that simple term but he uses it anyway for simplicities sake. I know this sounds super nit-picky, and it is, but you wrote "never" and that's always a slippery word when it comes to language.

Comment: I did statistical studies on the use of *wollen* recently, so I ran into that question before. When I say "Ich will am WE meine Steuer machen", it is safe to assume that I don't like to do my taxes. However, I came to the conclusion that intention and wish, may it even be remote, cannot be separated: although I don't like to do taxes, it is still my wish to do them this WE and not, say, next one. Next problem is that you can only assume, but not discern for sure what the speaker meant. So when he used *wollen* instead of neutral *werden*, it is prudent to assume he had a reason.