# How do you go from "wollen" in Konjunktiv II in indirect speech to direct speech?

Tags: modal-verb

Consider the use of *wollen* in these passages.

> A: Da erzählte er [der Königssohn] ihr, er wäre von einer bösen Hexe verwünscht worden, und niemand hätte ihn aus dem Brunnen erlösen können als sie allein, und morgen **wollten** sie zusammen in sein Reich gehen.  ([Der Froschkönig oder der eiserne Heinrich](http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/der_froschkonig_oder_der_eiserne_heinrich).)
>
> B: Wenn du [der Arzt] zu einem Kranken gerufen wirst, so will ich [der Gevatter Tod] dir jedesmal erscheinen: steh ich zu Häupten des Kranken, so kannst du keck sprechen, du **wolltest** ihn wieder gesund machen, und gibst du ihm dann von jenem Kraut ein, so wird er genesen; steh ich aber zu Füssen des Kranken, so ist er mein, und du musst sagen, alle Hilfe sei umsonst und kein Arzt in der Welt könne ihn retten.  ([Der Gevatter Tod](http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/der_gevatter_tod).)

When deriving direct speech from indirect speech as above, should you convert *wollen* in Konjunktiv II to the present indicative or keep it in K.II?

That is to say, which of the following is correct (or better)?

> For A: Ich bin von einer bösen Hexe verwünscht worden, und niemand hätte mich aus dem Brunnen erlösen können als Sie allein, und morgen **wollen** / **wollten** wir zusammen in mein Reich gehen.
>
> For B: Ich **will** / **wollte** ihn wieder gesund machen.

The motivation for the question is as follows.

- From [another discussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24502/does-wollen-ever-function-like-english-will-to-signal-a-future-event-no-vol), I gather that the element of volition in *wollen* can be weak.
- From [standard grammar](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Egerman/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivII.html), I gather that Konjunktiv II can soften a claim or statement.

I wondered whether these or any other considerations might recommend the use of the present indicative or K.II in direct speech of the sort as above. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what "morgen" is... the day that follows the day of the utterance or the day that follows the day of narrating the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A: "Morgen wollen wir zusammen in mein Reich gehen". That can either be a definitive expression of shared intent. It could also possibly be a future marker of an act which is certainly going to happen.

B: "Ich will ihn wieder gesund machen". Note that it is unclear whether or not the good doctor just has the intention or also the knowledge that he certainly will be able to cure the patient.

In both cases I tried to give some background on the possible ambiguities in these statements. I'm not entirely sure where that comes from, but it has something to do with the language in your examples, which is not really outdated but certainly sounds quite quaint.

Comment: Thank you. Does your answer imply that the correct version of direct speech should use the indicative present rather than K.II?

Comment: @Catomic One usually upvotes to say *thank you.* :)

Comment: Wenn es veraltet klingt - was wäre denn ein moderner Klang? Vermeidet man solche Konjunktive? Meinst Du nicht der veraltete Klang käme nur aus dem Kontext?

Comment: @Catomic: Most welcome and thanks for the upvote! Well, yes. But it doesn't mean that KII is wrong in direct speech, just in _this_ case it would be wrong to use KII to transform the indirect into direct speech. I guess you're aware of that, though.

Comment: @user unknown: I assume you're referring to the original text Catomic posted? I posit that you would write something like: "Da erzählte der Königssohn ihr, dass er von einer bösen Hexe verwünscht worden sei und niemand ihn aus dem Brunnen erlösen könnte als sie, und dass sie morgen zusammen in sein Reich gehen würden." That still sounds quaint because of the vocabulary used and because of the general theme, but I feel that it is grammatically a bit simpler and less convoluted.

Comment: Du weichst der Frage aus. Ich wollte absehen vom Kontext "Märchen", dem zweifellos etwas Altes anhaftet. Die Frage ist, ob die Form veraltet ist. Ob Deine Alternative einfacher ist, ist auch eine andere Frage, oder ist einfacher generell moderner? Das mittlere Bildungsniveau sollte ja gestiegen sein, verglichen mit der Produktionszeit des Froschkönigs. Jedenfalls erscheinen mir die Konstruktionen mit 'dass' weniger schön und elegant.

Comment: Und _Du_ machst eine als Anschuldigung formulierte Aussage gegen einen Dir vollkommen unbekannten Menschen, dessen Intentionen Dir gar nicht bekannt sein können. Der Rest ist zu einem großen Teil subjektiv, das stimmt schon. Ich habe darüber nachgedacht, in wiefern sich hier sprachliche von inhaltlicher Form auseinanderdividieren lassen und komme aber zu keinem Schluß - vielleicht ja Du?